# how to exclude blank values in jquery array?

Tags: jquery

there are following input fields with datepicker class:

```
<input type="text" class="datepicker" value="" />
<input type="text" class="datepicker" value="" />
<input type="text" class="datepicker" value="2011-02-15" />
<input type="text" class="datepicker" value="2011-02-16" />
```

I need to create an array of dates, exclude blank values and return maximum value. Following code doesn't seem to exclude blank values:

```
var datelist = [];
$(".datepicker").each(function(i) {
    if (this.value!="") {datelist[i] = this.value;}
});
datelist.sort();
datelist.reverse();
alert(datelist); //,,2011-02-16,2011-02-15
alert(datelist[0]); //undefined
```

What's the catch?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It excludes the empty values. That is why `datalist[0]` is `undefined`.

The value with index `0` is empty, hence `datelist[0] = this.value;` is not executed. The only values set in the array are the ones with keys `2` and `3`, making the keys `0`, `1` and all `>3` `undefined`.

If the values were included, you would not get `undefined` but an empty string.

You should not use the index for adding values to the array. `push()` them:

```
$(".datepicker").each(function(i) {
    if (this.value!="") {datelist.push(this.value);}
});
```

---

That said, a more concise way would be:

```
var datelist = $('.datepicker[value!=""]').map(function() {
    return this.value;
}).get();
```

**Reference:** [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/), [`.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/)

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$('.datepicker[value!=""]')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `.map` and `$.grep` methods to get the array and remove the empty items:

Get all values into an array:

```
var datelist = $(".datepicker").map(function() { return this.value; }).get();
```

Remove empty items from the array:

```
datelist = $.grep(datelist, function(s) { return s.length != 0; });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this portion -

```
var datelist = [];
$(".datepicker").each(function(i) {
    if (this.value!="") {datelist[i] = this.value;}
});
```

to this -

```
var datelist = [];
var index = 0;
$(".datepicker").each(function(i) {
    if ( $(this).val() != "") 
    {
        datelist[index++] = $(this).val();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's like doing `a = []; a[0] = 1; a[2] = 3;` - if you skip an index it will be filled with an `undefined` value. So you could change your code to something like this:

```
$(".datepicker").each(function() {
    if (this.value != "" || this.value != undefined) {
          datelist[datelist.length] = this.value;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First, do not use `this` in each but the second function argument - see http://fixingthesejquery.com/#slide29

Then, append values to the list instead of using an index (remember, you do not create an array element for some values of `i`!):

```
if (this.value) {
    datelist.push(this.value); 
}
```

So, the code should be like this:

```
var dateList = [];
$(".datepicker").each(function(i, elem) {
    if (elem.value) {
        dateList[i] = elem.value;
    }
});
dateList.sort();
dateList.reverse();
```

Comment: The OP is iterating over a jQuery object, not a regular array - using `this` is safe.